# Remove local user and data from windows 10 using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, file-permissions, file-access

I’m attempting to remove a local user from a computer (named Deltagare). I need to remove both the account and the files associated with the account inside `C:/Users/username`. I have issues with getting access denied event when running the script as administrator. The script is run on an administrator account. I have tried to transfer ownership, both by using `takeown`, `icacls` and `Set-Acl` but I still get access denied at Remove-Item

```
Remove-LocalUser -Name "Deltagare"
# Grant ownership here using takeown, icacls or Set-Acl
Remove-Item -Path "\\?\C:\Users\Deltagare" -Recurse
```

How do I delete this folder using Powershell? Any ideas on how to take ownership or do I need to remove the user another way?

Comment: You may read the following blog post: [Use PowerShell delete a user profile (step-by-step guide)](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easiest with CIM/WMI, in my opinion. You'll probably want to remove it before removing the user account, however.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile |
    Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.EndsWith($UserName) } |
    Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-Whatif` parameter to actually remove the profile, of course.

Filtering by the SID is probably even better than filtering by the username in th local path.

Comment: Sometimes the localpath ends in ".001" etc.

Comment: @js2010 Definitely. That's one reason why I recommended SID lookups.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a local account sounds like one task, but it will at least consist of the following three steps:

1. Delete the account from the local account database
2. Delete the profile directory of this account
3. Delete the account profile from the registry

The following function will perform these three tasks:

```bsh
function Remove-LocalUserCompletely {

    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        $Name
    )

    process {
        $user = Get-LocalUser -Name $Name -ErrorAction Stop

        # Remove the user from the account database
        Remove-LocalUser -SID $user.SID

        # Remove the profile of the user (both, profile directory and profile in the registry)
        Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile | ? SID -eq $user.SID | Remove-CimInstance
    }
}

# Example usage:
Remove-LocalUserCompletely -Name 'myuser'
```

You can read more about the deletion of local user accounts/profiles in [my answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/1570605/1077440).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the sid and remove the profile using the sid.  This would take care of both the folder and the registry entry for it.

```
$sid = get-ciminstance win32_useraccount | where name -eq myuser | % sid
get-ciminstance win32_userprofile | where sid -eq $sid | Remove-CimInstance -whatif
```

Comment: How would this work? `name` is not a member of the object returned by `Get-CimInstance`. pwsh 7.3.8

Comment: @lit works for me