# How to delete an application user's folder?

Tags: windows, powershell, qt, windows-10

I create a user when I install my Qt application. This user stores some data. So, when I uninstall my app, I want to remove the user and their data.

To achieve this, I initially used the following command:

```
Remove-LocalUser -Name "myuser"
```

This command successfully removes the user but does not delete the user folder data. Subsequently, I attempted to use:

```
rd /s /q C:\Users\myuser
```

However, this command exited with an error:

> The process cannot access the file because this file is used by another process.

This error is displayed for the *UsrClass.dat* and *NTUSER.dat* files.

I also attempted to install *PowerToys* to identify the program using these files, but I couldn't find any relevant information.

The only solution I found is to restart the computer and then delete the user folder. However, I would like to perform the deletion during my application's uninstallation process.

When attempting to delete the files in the file explorer, the following error is displayed:

> The action can't be completed because the file is open by SYSTEM.

Comment: Try [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle). Also, are there any processes running as the account-to-be-removed?

Comment: You may try this approach: [Delete User Profiles with PowerShell & CIM](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/)

Comment: @vonPryz Thank you for your reply. I have "No matching handles found." with handle. And I don't have any processes running as the user account...

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for your reply. I tried this approach but I have the same error...

Comment: Looks like the OS is working there. Maybe antivirus. Set a registry key to [delete the dir](https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2020/06/26/use-pendingfilerenameoperations-registry-key-to-automatically-delete-a-file-on-reboot/) on next reboot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove local user and data from windows 10 using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656577/remove-local-user-and-data-from-windows-10-using-powershell)